# .click function not working within an ajax POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two scripts that run on my page, that work on their own, but not together. The first part of the script is an ajax POST which selects rows from my database based on a search. This is all presented within a modal window. The second script waits for a click within the .btnSave id, closes the modal window and copies the value of the id into the last row of a table.

The two javascript files together are:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$('.btnSave').click(function() {
        alert();
var value = this.id;

$('#tablemain tbody tr:last #itemlookup').val(value);
$('#tablemain tbody tr:last #itemlookup').focus();
$('#productlookup').modal('hide');
});


$("#simple-post").click(function()
{
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
{

    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();

    $.ajax(
    {
        url : "ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data) 
        {
            $("#simple-msg").html(data);

        }

    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action

});

$("#ajaxform").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
});

});
```

The main PHP file including the modal window:

```
<div id="productlookup" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog"> 

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Instant Car Parts Stock Lookup</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="main-content">
      <section class="with-table"><form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" action="ajax.php" method="POST">
      <div id="simple-msg"></div><div class="vehilcle-form-sect">
             <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 "><p align="center"><input type="text" name="vehicleid" placeholder="VehicleID / Search Below"></p></div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">

                  <p align="center">
          <input type="button"  id="simple-post" value="Search" />
                  </p>
                </div>


        </div></form>


        </section>
          </div>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And finally the ajax.php (which works fine):

```
<?php include("../../config.php");
include('../../includes/session.php');
session_start(); ?>
<table class="datatable tablesort selectable paginate full" width="100%">

                       <tbody>
                         <?php 

 if ($_POST['make']) { 
 $breaker_id = $_SESSION['breaker_id'];
 $Make = $_POST['make'];
 $Model = $_POST['model'];
 $Year = $_POST['year']; 


 $show=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stock where breaker='$breaker_id' and Make='$Make' and Model='$Model' and (Year = '".$Year."' OR YearRange LIKE '%".$Year."%')");

 }

 if ($_POST['vehicleid']) { 
 $breaker_id = $_SESSION['breaker_id'];
 $vehicleid = $_POST['vehicleid'];



$show=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stock where breaker='$breaker_id' and VehicleID='$vehicleid' AND VehicleID!=''");


 }


$xx = 1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($show)){



?>
                           <tr id="row_<?php echo $xx; ?>">
                             <td><strong class="btnSave" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['id']; ?>
    </strong>
                               <p><?php echo $row['stock_item']; ?> &pound;<?php echo $row['price']; ?></p>
                              </td>
                           </tr><?php

$xx++;
}  ?>
                       </tbody>
          </table>
```

I'm presuming it is because the javascript doesn't recognise the .btnSave since it's loaded after the ajax?

Comment: Your presumption is correct. Injected html snippets need their events attached after rendering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case you can use event delegation with [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnSave', function() {...});
```

Note that the jquery context must exist at a binding moment and it should contain all dynamically added elements. To ensure this you can use `$(document)` as context since it obviously exists at a page load. Selector defining your binding DOM element (`'.btnSave'`) should be passed as second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing:
`$('.btnSave').click(function() {`
to
`$('.btnSave').live('click', function() {` or `$('.btnSave').on('click', function() {`

Please note, your current code is open to SQL injection attacks. Consider sanitizing your inputs.

Comment: live() is depricated !

Comment: @fico7489 so is mysql_query in their PHP code, suggesting a legacy application. jQuery version isn't clear from the question, hence several options being offered in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
$(".btnSave").on("click", function(){
    //doo what you need
});
```

not

```
$(".btnSave").click(function(){
    //doo what you need
});
```

because this way function works on dynamicly added dom elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a delegate ...

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

```
$("#simple-msg").on("click", ".btnSave", function(){
 // do stuff here
})
```